# Submanifolds of nilmanifolds coming from Lie subgroups

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a connected simply connected nilpotent real Lie group and $\Gamma$ a lattice in $G$, such that $M=\Gamma \backslash G$ is a compact nilmanifold. Let $p:G \to M$ be the projection. If $S$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$ (coming from a Lie subalgebra of $Lie(G)$), is $p(S) \subset M$ a (embedded, immersed) submanifold?

My only intuition comes from the abelian case, where I think the answer is yes. But this is very particular since in this case the nilmanifold itself is also a Lie group and everything works easier.

Comment: Yes. The left cosets $gS$ of $S$ form a foliation and this foliation is invariant under left multiplication, and in particular under left multiplication of $\Gamma$ so they induce a foliation on the left quotient $\Gamma\backslash G$.